# Background Agent

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, service

Windows phones won't support background agents in release mode.Is it true?.
Is there any equivalent application type available in windows phone as Android's service  for processing network intensive operations?

My requirement is to start a background service application (which will process network operations in a thread) from a foreground application.

Although this information can be obtained by google , i need some sort of expert advise who is working with silverlight and windows phone.

Comment: Tis may be helpful: [Background file transfers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: msdn says that the maximum size allowed for background upload over cellular connection is only 5 MB.My files are of size 8 MB.Please Suggest me some other methods if possible.                          I am okay with the 20 MB limit provided for wifi connection.But my goal is to upload files over GPRS/3G/EDGE connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does support background agents in release mode.

The difference is that in DEBUG mode you have a greater level of control over when they start (via the `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest()` method).
In release mode the OS takes complete control over when a periodic background agent will run. It's typically, approximately, every 30 minutes though.

Windows Phone 7 does not support any kind of application running continually in the background (like a service) so it's probably not possible to do what you are attempting.
If you can provide more details of what you're trying to achieve, rather than what you do elsewhere, then we may be able to advise further.

**Update based on comments**

If you wish to upload lots of data from a device then the best approach is to break it into sections (partial files) of no more than 5MB and then POST to the server using a [BackgroundTransferRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh220722%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). (A BTR has a 5MB limit on uploads.)

Comment: My requirement is to upload multiple files (of size 8MB) to server when network connection is available.As in msdn , if execution of periodic agent is only for 25 seconds per 30 minutes , then achieving my goal is little bit complicated.Upon each execution , only part file can be uploaded.Suggest me some alternative methods if possible.

Comment: The supported protocols for BackgroudTransferRequest are Http and Https.Is there any api which supports TCP?

Comment: And more over , for transfering data over 2g using BackgroundTransferRequest , application has to be in foreground.Without foreground view ,BackgroundTransfer will work in 3g or higher network modes.